# AngularJS not setting location state with "skipReload"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a site that is transitioning to Angular - it uses Angular for single page application navigation and a new feature I'm currently working on is written entirely in Angular.

The rest of the site takes navigation results and returns them through the SPA model, the feature I'm working on runs entirely in a single page, but in order to make links shareable and bookmarkable it changes the URL in relation to the current state of the page.

So when someone selects a new subsection of the new feature, we have some code like this in the subsection service:

```
function setLocationForSubsection(subsection) {
        var path = subsection.id ? "subsections/" + subsection.id + "/" + subsection.urlSlug : "";
        $location.path("/section/" + path).search({}).skipReload();
    };
```

If they follow a link to elsewhere in the site ( which goes through a `$stateProvider.state('all', { url: '*urlPath?id', controller...` pattern ) it works correctly.

If they then hit the back button, they come back to the correct page and `setLocationForSubsection` is called. If they click on the same link outside of the subsection again, nothing happens.

So this course of action occurs:

1. `/section/2/subsection-name` <- works.
2. `/news` <- works
3. back button ( `/section/2/subsection-name` ) <- works
4. `/news` **fails**

As far as I can tell, the problem arises because the location path setting fails to push the location into the angular state in this situation, so as far as angular is concerned it is still on `/news` and so when I try to navigate back there, it doesn't pick it up as a navigation event. I have tried using `$window.history.pushState(null, 'any', $location.absUrl());` manually, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. If I drop the `skipReload` call it works but reloads the contents of the page, which is superfluous in this case. I'm using that approach for now, but I would like to know if there is a better option.

Is there a way to tell angular that a state change has happened in this case?